# Schema validation error cvc-elt.4.2 (despite correct type definition?)

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm trying to validate an xml file against the schema "http://xml.ra.se/e-arkiv/METS/CSPackageMETS.xsd" and I'm getting the following validation error:

cvc-elt.4.2: Cannot resolve 'premis:file' to a type definition for element 'premis:object'

In the xml file I have this:

```
<premis:object xmlns:premis="info:lc/xmlns/premis-v2" version="2.2" xsi:schemaLocation="info:lc/xmlns/premis-v2 http://www.loc.gov/standards/premis/v2/premis-v2-2.xsd" xsi:type="premis:file">
```

The problem is that as far as I can see, "premis:file" is a defined type definition according to premis. But maybe I'm not interpretating this correctly, I'm new to schemas and actually xml in general.

I have searched for information that could help me understand what is happening in the xml file and how it is related to the schema in order to understand what is wrong but I have not been able to find an answer to this problem. I'd bee most grateful for help on this.

The xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII" standalone="no"?>
<mets:mets xmlns:mets="http://www.loc.gov/METS/" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" OBJID="bc198c15-cd31-41e6-98aa-5e85caf97d6c" PROFILE="http://xml.ra.se/e-arkiv/METS/CommonSpecificationSwedenPackageProfile.xml" TYPE="Economics" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.loc.gov/METS/ http://www.loc.gov/standards/mets/version18/mets.xsd http://xml.ra.se/e-arkiv/METS/CSPackageMETS.xsd">
      <mets:metsHdr CREATEDATE="2016-04-22T08:39:09"><mets:agent ROLE="ARCHIVIST" TYPE="ORGANIZATION"><mets:name>arkivbildare</mets:name></mets:agent><mets:agent ROLE="ARCHIVIST" TYPE="ORGANIZATION"><mets:name>nummer</mets:name></mets:agent><mets:agent OTHERTYPE="SOFTWARE" ROLE="ARCHIVIST" TYPE="OTHER"><mets:name>system</mets:name></mets:agent><mets:agent ROLE="CREATOR" TYPE="ORGANIZATION"><mets:name>levorg</mets:name></mets:agent><mets:altRecordID TYPE="SUBMISSIONAGREEMENT">bet;2016-05-31</mets:altRecordID></mets:metsHdr>
      <mets:amdSec ID="amdSec_1">
        <mets:techMD ID="techMD_1">
          <mets:mdWrap MDTYPE="PREMIS:OBJECT">
            <mets:xmlData>
              <premis:object xmlns:premis="info:lc/xmlns/premis-v2" version="2.2" xsi:schemaLocation="info:lc/xmlns/premis-v2 http://www.loc.gov/standards/premis/v2/premis-v2-2.xsd" xsi:type="premis:file"> some elements </premis:object>
             </mets:xmlData>
          </mets:mdWrap>
       </mets:techMD>
    some elements
    </mets:amdSec>
    some elements
 </mets:mets>
```

Comment: Do you want to use the schema `http://www.loc.gov/standards/premis/v2/premis-v2-2.xsd` given in the `schemaLocation` attribute?

Comment: The whole file should validate to the schema http://xml.ra.se/e-arkiv/METS/CSPackageMETS.xsd but I assume that it is the schema in the schemaLocation attribute that is relevant for my problem?

Comment: Even after your update, you've still not posted a ***[mcve]***.  Your XML should validate except for the single error that's the subject of your question.   (It's not even close.  Your `schemaLocation` on the root element has an odd number of entries, `premis:object is incomplete, etc.)  **Get your XML example cleaned-up so that it can cleanly illustrate your actual problem, and then update your question.**  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add a declaration of the `xsi` namespace prefix,

```
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

to the `premis:object` element,

```
<premis:object version="2.2"
               xmlns:premis="info:lc/xmlns/premis-v2"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xsi:schemaLocation="info:lc/xmlns/premis-v2 
                            http://www.loc.gov/standards/premis/v2/premis-v2-2.xsd"
               xsi:type="premis:file"/>
```

then you'll get past the `xsi:schemaLocation` problem.

Of course, the above `premis:object` element is incomplete, so the next error you'll encounter will be

> [Error] try.xml:6:40: cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element
>   'premis:object' is not complete. One of
>   '{"info:lc/xmlns/premis-v2":objectIdentifier}' is expected.

but presumably the rest of your unposted XML will address that.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have a declaration of the xsi namespace prefix in the root element (sorry for not mentioning), do I still need to add a declaration to the premis:object element? Why is that in that case?

Comment: No, an `xsi` declaration on the root element should suffice.  Please post a [mcve] of your XML so that we can more easily help you.  Thanks.

Comment: That's still far from a [mcve] illustrating the problem.  What you post should be ***valid*** except for the single error which is the subject of your question.   That XML has a bad `schemaLocation` (odd number of entries), incomplete `premis:object`, etc.   You've got to put some time into your question before posting.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this. About the schemaLocation attribute, this is what I've got and I didn't know it was a problem since the validator didn't complain. I'll see if I can find what's missing.

Comment: When it comes to the elements under premis:object, the code would get extremely large if I included everything so I thought it was best not to include it. Since my validator seemed to go from top to bottom and stop when it reached a problem I thought it wouldn't matter to this problem. Since my validator stops when it reaches my problem I can't validate the code that comes after. I will try to read the schema in order to understand what is necessary to include.